# c# Randomize DataTable rows

Tags: c#, datatable, datasource, repeater

I have a Data Table I'm using as the data source for a repeater and would like to have the results show in a random order each time it's called.

I've been able to do this while retrieving the data but wish to cache the result set before it's bound.

Is the any was to shuffle or randomise the rows of a data table before binding to the repeater?

CODE:

```
        TreeProvider tp = new TreeProvider();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sKey = "KEY";
    using (CachedSection<DataSet> cs = new CachedSection<DataSet>(ref ds, 5, true, null, sKey))
    {
      if (cs.LoadData)
      {
        ds = tp.SelectNodes("", "URL", "", true, "DOCTYPE", "", "NewID()", -1, true, 5);
        cs.Data = ds;
      }
    }
    if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(ds))
    {
      rprItems.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
      rprItems.DataBind();
    }
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far to the question?

Comment: Didn't feel the need as it's generic. Added now...

Comment: Here's a link which could be helpful for you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b832b9ff-5e1a-490f-bcf6-3e72070b5879/shuffle-datatable-rows

Comment: Isn't that the point of the NewID() column you are bringing in from your SQL?  Aren't you ordering by that in the SQL statement to randomize the row order?

Comment: Vincent James yes and no. That does randomise it, but like I said I'm caching the data so it's only random every 5 minutes. I need it to be random every time the datasource is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking a copy of the table, adding a field and assigning a random number to each row then ordering by that row.

```
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("SortBy"))
          dt.Columns.Add("SortBy", typeof (Int32));

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
          col.ReadOnly = false;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
          row["SortBy"] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        }
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "SortBy";
        DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();

        rprItems.DataSource = sortedDT;
        rprItems.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, I know it's not pretty but:

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.TableName = "<NewTableName>";
//Make a new Random generator
Random rnd = new Random();
while (<new table length> != <old table length>)
{
    //We'll use this to make sure we don't have a duplicate row
    bool rowFound = false;
    //index generation
    int index = rnd.Next(0, <max number of rows in old data>);
    //use the index on the old table to get the random data, then put it into the new table.
    foreach (DataRow row in newTable.Rows)
    {
        if (oldTable.Rows[index] == row)
        {
            //Oops, there's duplicate data already in the new table. We don't want this.
            rowFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!rowFound)
    {
        //add the row to newTable
        newTable.Rows.Add(oldTable.Rows[index];
    }
}
```

You'll have to use your own tables, names, and lengths of course, but this should be ok to use. If there's a lot of data, this could take a while. It's the best I can come up with, and it's untested. I'm curious to know if it works.

Comment: Random class is pseudo random number generator, it will never create true random numbers

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do random. Every answer so far has a similar suggestion.

Comment: Check my answer, it doesn't , it has reference to True Random number generator using System.Cryptography

Comment: I put Random and your Custom Random into a program and tested them. The only difference I see is that Random can only be initialized one time or you get the same number multiple times, while yours can be initialized over and over, and could possibly have a same number, but not likely. Nice stuff.

Comment: RNGCryptoServiceProvider used in my example, is capable of generating true random number, even with same object and seed, does not require new object every time, vis a vis Random class, which starts repeating the numbers after sometime / iteration due to its pseudo nature

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Sort");
        dt.Rows.Add("TEST");
        dt.Rows.Add("TEST1");
        dt.Rows.Add("TEST2");

        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row["Sort"] = rnd.Next(dt.Rows.Count);
        }


        var dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = "Sort";
        foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
        }
```

If your datatable is not too big it should do it.

Comment: Random class is pseudo random number generator, it will never create true random numbers

Comment: You can replace for whatever you want. Change the sort column to guid and generate a new Guid will do the same trick as SQL. Remember that so far we dont need to generate a unique random number, the idea is just random sort results. Keep it simple unless you need complicated solutions